# Searching for car displacement data

Tags: dataset, spatial, networks, spatio-temporal

I am starting a work on electric vehicle to see how the charging process can impact the local electricity network. I would like to know if there exists public data of driving "habits".

Ideally, I would like time series data for bigh fleets of vehicles in a relatively big city. For a given car these data could be a series of date telling when and where the car stops and when it starts again. It could also contain the associated consumption of energy and driving distance between to stop. I know I am asking too much but would like to know if anyone is aware of an intermediate dataset.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The US Census Bureau maintains aggregate data of amount of time taken to go to work and of car ownership.  I believe this is available at the block group level (about 100 households).  A point of departure is http://www.fhwa.dot.gov/planning/census_issues/ctpp/ .  Look at the AASHTO site, too: http://ctpp.transportation.org/Pages/3yrdas.aspx

Comment: Perhaps  http://getthedata.org/  might yield some useful suggestions. It's specifically designed to answer questions about where to locate datasets.

Comment: Thanks @whuber and @Jeromy !  you're so fast ! I might want statistics about the average time that it takes you both to answer a question (for example the time that it takes from when the question is written to when you writte something about it:)). Anyway,  I'll take a look at these sites and tell later if I founded something interesting...

Comment: Also I have noticed that Google has a format for these type of data GTFS ... i don't see any R equivalent that would be build  on sp package classes. Is someone aware of something about an R package under developpment around that GTFS ?

Comment: Now there is open data SE site where this W would be moe appropriate

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for data, try:

http://www.zanran.com

===========================

Here are some additional links that might help:

http://pubs.its.ucdavis.edu/download_pdf.php?id=1387

http://www.its.ucdavis.edu/people/faculty/kurani/index.php

http://www.nrel.gov/docs/fy09osti/46251.pdf

http://s3.amazonaws.com/zanran_storage/www.inl.gov/ContentPages/110551078.pdf

http://s3.amazonaws.com/zanran_storage/trb.org/ContentPages/520326.pdf

Comment: Thanks, The publication from Jonn Axsen *, Kenneth S. Kurani is interesting. In my question was more about getting data and I have to try zanran to see what it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed there is a data format [GTFS](http://code.google.com/intl/fr-FR/transit/spec/transit_feed_specification.html) created by Google for public transportation data. There is an [interesting repository](http://www.gtfs-data-exchange.com/) with public data all around the world. The only thing that is missing is a R package/S4 class that would extend [sp-classes](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/sp.pdf)  with POSIXct and permit to read this type of data. Someone motivated to work on that ? Are there already ongoing work ?

Comment: That seems like a question suited for the [GIS site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/). While the R users on the site are limited, potentially other programs have compiled that data into other formats suitable for geoprocessing tools. I have seen several web mapping examples use that info, and so I suspect some on the GIS site do have experience with it (or at least knowledge of it).